# How to create form-maker with nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, forms

I'm trying to make a **form-maker** with *Node.Js* and *MongoDB* but confused about the data structure.
By the way, I created a `form.model` to store the form structure:

```
{
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Form must have a title']
    },
    users: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        role: Number
    }],
    owner: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    active: {type: Boolean, default: true},
    fields: [{
        case_id: String,
        label: String,
        type: Number, //1:selective, 2:descriptive, 3:range
        required: Boolean,
        default: {
            title: String,
            value: Number,
        },
        placeholder: String,
        items:[{
            label: String,
            value: Number,
        }],
        range:[{
            min: Number,
            max: Number,
            step: Number,
            default: {type: Number, default: 0}
        }]
    }]
}
```

and a `form.data.model` to store the data of forms:

```
{
    form: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Form',
        required: true
    },
    fields_data: {
        "case_id": Object //value per case_id
    }
}
```

Is that true? or there is the best practice for that?
If I modify the form fields how control the data about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've created the structure of my **form-maker** data.

`form.model:`

```
{
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Form must have a title']
    },
    owner: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: [true, 'Form must have a owner']
    },
    active: {type: Boolean, default: true},
    deleted: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    fields: [{
        name: String, //that field id and must be auto generated and not be modified by end user
        label: String,
        type: Number, //1:Selective, 2:Descriptive, 3:Range
        required: Boolean,
        placeholder: String,
        selectable_items:[{
            label: String,
            value: Number,
            selected: Boolean
        }],
        range:[{
            min: Number,
            max: Number,
            step: Number,
            default: {type: Number, default: 0}
        }]
    }]
}
```

`form.users.model:`

```
{
    form: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Form',
        required: true
    },
    users: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User',
            role: Number //0:Admin, 1:Editor, 3:Viewer
        }
    ]
}
```

`form.values.model:`

```
{
    form: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Form',
        required: true
    },
    values: [
        {
            name: String,
            value: Object
        }
    ]
}
```